# Weird edit on Meta: No appropriate change and markdown option is missing

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I just encountered a suggested edit here on Meta that looked like this:

[image: Suggested-edit review view]

There are two things weird here:

- There was no option to distinguish between *rendered output* and *markdown* like this:
  [image: Your regular interface to switch between rendered output and markdown.]

  This is also missing from the [review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/37963).
- The *[off-topic]* marked in green in the above screenshot was the only visible change in the rendered diff. This is something an edit should not be able to change. Also, without it, there is nothing left to give the edit the minimum character count (though there may be some invisible aspects that I could not see, because I could not access the markdown view of the suggested edit.

Comment: No bug here, it's a "title only" edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you know that the titles can't haz markdown. So this is the way in which title edits are displayed when an editor only made changes in the title (or tags, they don't have markdown also).

> The [off-topic] marked in green in the above screenshot was the only visible change in the rendered diff.

Yes, and the only one. What's wrong with it? It didn't bypass any special rules...

> This is something an edit should not be able to change.

Why? [off-topic] is not reserved by the system. It is not [closed], [duplicate], or [migrated], is it?

> Also, without it, there is nothing left to give the edit the minimum character count

Eh, anyone can suggest an edit changing *only* title. And 6-chars limit is required for the edit to be submitted  applies when you change *at least one char in body*.

Comment: Just to clarify: Anyone, regardless of rep, can suggest title-only edits that are fewer than six characters? I recently came across a well-written question with a typo requiring deletion of two characters in the title. Thinking I wasn't allowed to fix it, I had a high-rep friend do it. Are you saying I could have done that myself?

Comment: @Sue Yes, and you could have done it yourself :) Title edits *do  not* have 6-chars-requirement.

Comment: I think, this has at least one feature request coming.

Comment: @wrz Which one? Allow markdown in titles? :D

Comment: @nicael: No, indicate title only changes as such. Perhaps also: Do not allow to append something like *[off-topic]* to a title.

Comment: For the protocol: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251462/255554) is the first one.